# removing subfolder and get pageName in url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the sub folder from url and get the page name from the url using `.htaccess`.

Suppose my real directory structure is:

```
 /public_html/promoted-content/gui/promoted-content.php
 /public_html/promoted-content/pages.php
```

### Pages.php

```
 switch($_GET['pageName']) {

    case 'home': {
        include "gui/promoted-content.php";
        break;
    }

    case 'promoted-content-news': {
        $default_title = "News | ".$default_title;
        include "gui/promoted-content.php";
        break;
    }


    case 'promoted-content-news-details': {
        $default_title = "News | ".$default_title;
        include "gui/promoted_contentdetail.php";
        break;
    }
```

### .htaccess

```
  RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ promoted-content/index.php?pageName=pages&id=$1    [NC,L]    # Process Pagename requests
```

So, I want url `www.example.com/promoted-content/gui/promoted-content.php?id=1` to be rewrited as:

```
 www.example.com/promoted-content-news/pageid/pagetitle
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch 3 parameters in .htaccess , one for your pageName, one for id, and one for title:

```
#make sure existing files and directories work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ promoted-content/index.php?pageName=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

Comment: var_dump($_GET) in promoted-content/index.php and post here. What do u see? What is your erro? It didnt work, tells me nothing

Comment: I want to make sure in which directory should I put the .htaccess. If I put `.htaccess` in `/promoted-content/.htaccess` then how to achieve the url as I wanted. I var_dump but I didn't get anything.

Comment: You put .htacces in your root /

Comment: I var_dump. But didn't get any get request in index.php in `/promoted-content/index.php`

Comment: do you put RewriteEngine On on top of .htaccess ? what do you get when you access custom urls?

Comment: Yes its already there. I don't get anything means I get just header and footer but nothing else.

Comment: Check ownership and permission of .htaccess because this solution works

Comment: permission is working well beacause I have other rule also that working well in same .htaccess file.

Comment: I recheked rules on my own server, works as expected. U have something else here.